# Wrong referrer in AJAX call after user redirected to a page by click on back button

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I've noticed one interesting thing in Chrome browser. For example, we have two pages on our site: A and B, both pages load script X which makes AJAX call to a server. When user goes to the page A, requests to the script X and AJAX call has URL of the page A as referrer. That's fine. On the page A we have a link to page B. If user click on it he will be redirected to the page B. Here we load the script X and make the same AJAX call. Now the referrer in headers for the script X and AJAX call is the URL of page B. That is still fine. Now if user click back button he will be redirected to page A. The script X will be requested with referrer A, but the AJAX call has referrer B.

I hage two questions:

1. Why? If you try it in FireFox browser then it works as expected. All AJAX calls have the actual page URL as referrer.
2. How to fix it? Is there a way to fix it the referrer header or I can only set the referrer as GET/POST parameter?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using the jQuery.ajax method, try specifying the option cache to false : jQuery.ajax({ cache : false, ... });

Comment: Hi Ole. Yes, this is exactly what I need. I've just wanted to add the answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also found that the request is loaded from cache. I've added cache buster and now it's working fine.